# Check if key combination is not pressed

Tags: javascript

I need to check if the key combination `ctrl` + `alt` is not pressed.

To check if the key combination is pressed you can use a simple if statement:

```
if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey) {
   console.log("ctrl and alt pressed")
}
```

But how can I check of this key combination is not pressed?
I´ve tried to invert the if statment but this did not work:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownFunc, false);

function keyDownFunc(e) {
    if (!(e.ctrlKey && e.altKey)) {
    console.log("not pressed");
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xela84/39cq5oja/1/

I need that to switch a radiobutton with the arrow keys only if the `Alt Gr` key is not pressed:

```
this.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    // if e.target is vaadin-radio-group then assign to checkedRadioButton currently checked radio button
    var checkedRadioButton = (e.target == this) ? this._checkedButton : e.target;

    // Detect if Alt Gr is not pressed
    if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey) {

        // LEFT, UP - select previous radio button
        if (e.key === "ArrowLeft" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
            e.preventDefault();
            this._selectPreviousButton(checkedRadioButton);
        }

        // RIGHT, DOWN - select next radio button
        if (e.key === "ArrowRight" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
            e.preventDefault();
            this._selectNextButton(checkedRadioButton);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: adding ```else``` block to the first if statement didn't work?

Comment: What do u mean by "not pressed"? Isn't that just inverse of the first case?

Comment: add `else` statement

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu > If there's nothing to do in the "if" clause, that would be inelegant to use a "else" statement

Comment: why wouldn't `if (!(e.ctrlKey && e.altKey)) {}` work?

Comment: When are you expecting this event to be triggered? You can't have a "not pressed" event, because if nothing happens... well, there's no event.

Comment: As @LaurentS. said, there is nothing to do in the "if" clause. I need only the else clause.

Comment: inverting it should work 100%.....

Comment: You want something like this: `if (!e.ctrlKey && e.altKey || e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey)  {}`

Comment: I have a feeling if that code is not working there is another issue at play. Maybe we should see more code.

Comment: @ChatterOne i`ve updated my question to show, why I need the "not pressed" check.

Comment: I agree with @rajthakur , but it's actually simpler, you just need `if (!(e.ctrlKey || e.altKey)) {`

Comment: @ChatterOne but this will only catch the `ctrl` or `alt` key and not the combination of both

Comment: @xela84 Exactly. What you're asking is that if either is pressed, it should not be doing anything. In other words, if not (ctrl or alt).